# FT_SetFlowControl works without valid enumeration value

Tags: driver, serial-port, c++, ftdi

I have seen

```
FT_STATUS 
FT_SetFlowControl 
(FT_HANDLE ftHandle, USHORT usFlowControl, UCHAR uXon,UCHAR uXoff)
```

function works with a random value for usFlowControl other than "Must be one of FT_FLOW_NONE, FT_FLOW_RTS_CTS, FT_FLOW_DTR_DSR or FT_FLOW_XON_XOFF", but only in some instances. is this a known issue. is it a whim? please help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specifications of the device connected to the port and the cable.

If that device does not use that signal, no matter what value is set there is no effect.

In recent years, these signals are not used in many cases in terms of both improved device performance and cost reduction.